# Different headers for rest

Tags: php, rest, ionic2, request, http-headers

I'm creating a little mobile application in ionic with rest API.

I have a problem with request headers and I don't know how to set headers on server side or in application.

I have following code:

```
export function registration(data) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);

    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers})

    return this.http.post(API_URL, JSON.stringify(data), options)
                .toPromise()
                .then(response => validateResponseCode([202], response))
                .then(response => response.json());
}
```

screen all headers (local/prod)
[image: screen all headers (local/prod)]

When is API_URL located on localhost is everything ok and headers are set correctly (left side of image).

but when I change API_URL to production server headers are wrong and request failed. (right side of image)

I can edit mobile application or server (PHP), but I don't know what set.

I tried to set headers:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true ");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, 
X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control");
```

But it doesn't work.

Thank you for help

---

```
ionic -v 3.4.0
php -v 7.0.15
```

Comment: check your production server logs to see why its giving a 500 Internal Server Error?

Comment: Yes, because route is for method POST. But mobile application create method OPTIONS. 500 is because I do not have the default 404 yet...